# EXtJs:How to get value of checked radio button

Tags: extjs4

I am using Extjs4,I have a radiogroup and i want to get the checked radio button value,for that i had used listeners as follows,

```
var radiogroup = new Ext.form.RadioGroup({
    fieldLabel: 'Specimen ?',
    allowBlank: false,
    anchor: '85%',
    items: [
    {
      boxLabel: 'Yes',
      name: 'radio1',
      inputValue: 1
    },
    {
      boxLabel: 'No',
      name: 'radio2',
      inputValue: 2,
      checked:true
    }],
    listeners: {
      change : function(){                           
         if(createOrderForm.getForm().getValues()['radio1']==1){
            alert("yes"); 
         }else{
            alert("No");
         }

      }
   }
});
```

When i check 'yes' button,the condition is not satisfied and both alerts are firing. How to get the value of selected radio button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should use the same name for every radios in the same RadioGroup.

Second, replace the `change` handler for the RadioGroup with 2 `change` handler, one for each radio:

```
change : function(){ 
     if (this.getValue()) { // checked.
        alert("yes"); // or "no" 
     }
}
```

You should not use the `change` handler in RadioGroup because when clicking on the unchecked radio , the `change` event will fire twice (one when the old radio changes from "checked" to "unchecked", one when the new radio changes from "unchecked" to "checked")

Answer (score 0):

Use same name for radio buttons change: name 'radio1' and 'radio2' to a unique name, because the options are in same group